# How to get the linear PCM from a recording on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, pcm, audioqueueservices

I want to do something like speaker verification on iPhone (as a course project). And I'm wondering how to get linear PCM from the speaker. I read about the documentation about queue services, and it seems that it records the sound and then store it to a file. Is there a way to get the linear PCM directly from this? The documentation mentioned something about the buffer, but I don't quite understand that. Maybe it's the key to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio Queue Services is for doing this. Just type in the code you need in the call back function.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343

Answer (score 0):

```
        AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];
        audioRecorder.delegate = self;
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
```

then start recording using a NSTimer such as invoke the timer when you click the record button

```
    -(IBAction)record:(id)sender{
       NSTimer *recordTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self 
       selector:@selector(recordTimerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];     
    }

    -(void)recordTimerAction:(id)sender {

            [audioRecorder updateMeters];
            const double ALPHA = 0.05;
            double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [audioRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
            lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
            NSLog(@"The Amplitude of the recording Sound is %f",lowPassResults);
            NSLog(@"The Normal Linear PCM Value is %f",[audioRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
    }
```

// Delegate method

```
 -(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: (AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{

        [recordTimer invalidate];

    }
```

Comment: that the amplitude will be in the range from 0 to 1 ., that could be helpful

Comment: I found that apple has its built-int API for this which is called Audio Queue Services. I think your answer is correct, but the built-in API will be better.

Comment: @user1214321 Oh, That's Great if that is the better way!!